# C# and youtube video ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this script here

```
<object width="830" height="495">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEOIDHERE?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEOIDHERE?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
           allowscriptaccess="always" 
           allowfullscreen="true" width="830" height="495">
</object>
```

and in my code behind I have the videoID defined in a sting called videoID

How would I replace the VIDEOIDHERE with the videoID I have defined in the code behind?

I am using ASP.NET

Comment: Is this WPF/Winforms/Asp.net/MVC... ? You need to provide more context please.

Comment: Please, tell us wich technology are you using (asp.net, mvc, etc...) C# is only the language...

Comment: Is this raw html on the aspx file?

Comment: Show us the codebehind where you have the `videoID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that you have a property (that has an access modifier of protected or higher) named VideoId, this should do:

```
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/<%= VideoId %>?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" ...>
```